# Как вынести два разных числа?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

хочу для сайта сделать так, что бы в  выводил два разных числа, для сравнение цен без скидки и со скидкой. Заранее большое спасибо) (сорри если вопрос глупый)

```js
var s = document.forms.Sum,
  d = s.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not([value]), input[type="checkbox"][value=""]');
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) // чтобы не было написано NaN, убираем в disabled пункты, где не прописаны значения
  d[i].disabled = true;
s.onchange = function() { // начало работы функции сложения
  var n = s.querySelectorAll('[type = "checkbox"]'),
    itog = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < n.length; j++)
    n[j].checked ? itog += parseFloat(n[j].value) : itog;
  document.getElementById('rezult').innerHTML = itog + ' руб.';
  document.getElementById('rezult_1').innerHTML = itog + ' руб.';
}
```

```html
<form name="Sum">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>консультация</td>
      <th>бесплатно</th>
      <th>бесплатно</th>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" value="0">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>предварительный договор</td>
      <th><del>3 000</del></th>
      <th>1 500</th>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1500">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>сбор и подготовка документов</td>
      <th><del>6 000</del></th>
      <th>3 000</th>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="3000"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        основной договор<br> (купля-продаж, дарение, аренда)
      </td>
      <th><del>3 000</del></th>
      <th>1 500</th>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="1500"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ипотечная сделка</td>
      <th><del>10 000</del></th>
      <th>5 000</th>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="5000"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>сделка с мат.капиталом</td>
      <th><del>6 000</del></th>
      <th>3 000</th>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="3000"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        регистрация сделки в уфрс<br> (не нужно никуда ездить, стоять в очередях,<br> за вас все сделают юристы нашей компании.<br> вы просто заберете готовые документы<br> у нас в офисе)
      </td>
      <th><del>6 000</del></th>
      <th>3 000</th>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="3000"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>итого:</th>
      <th><del><form class = "sum"><output id = "rezult_1">0 руб.</output></form></del></th>
      <th><output id="rezult">0 руб.</output></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Судя по бешенным скидкам достаточно `itog * 2`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вот всегда так  ответ находиться на поверхности чем я думал )) реально глупый вопрос оказался)